# Flutter - Can't install apk on android

Tags: flutter, apk

I'm new to flutter and on a phone I have it works and the app runs fine, but I sent the apk to another device and it couldn't be installed, I don't know if it's because of a plugin I'm using that is "speech to speech", since in that plugin I changed the version of min sdk to 21 but the android that I try to install has an android version of 10 that is higher, it seems to me, what would be the cause?

Comment: translate your title

Answer (score 0):

Remember Android no longer accept the app which has not been signed as release,. make sure you are making you are signing the app correctly, Android studio will help you.

Comment: I'm using VsCode because Studio is too heavy. What should I do? I used this command: flutter build apk --build-name=1.0.0 --build-number=0    Does this mean the apk is signed?

Answer (score 0):

The build flavor should be release, and the signature must be created before. But the easiest way is to run the app in profile mode,

flutter run --profile

Profile mode run as release mode but doesn't require to be manually signed.

Answer (score 0):

There could be other reasons but do you know that the Flutter app cannot be installed on x86 Android

[Flutter does not currently support building for x86 Android](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#what-are-the-supported-target-architectures)